# Как обеспечить выход из приложения по сигналу?

Tags: qt, c++

В QtAssistant написано, что нужно коннектиться к слоту QCoreApplication::quit()
Я попробовал следующий код:

```
class Test : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Test(QObject *parent = 0);
signals:
    void exit();
public slots:
    void run() {emit exit();}
};
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    Test t;
    QObject::connect(&t, SIGNAL(exit()), &a, SLOT(quit()));
    t.run();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Приложение продолжает свою работу.. Что я не так делаю?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как правильно заметил aknew сигнал в Вашей программе испускается до запуска цикла обработки событий (a.exec()) поэтому он не производит никакого действия. Чтобы все сработало как надо нужно слегка модифицировать Вашу программу:

1. Испустить сигнал exit() после запуска цикла обработки событий.
2. для этого, например, запустить метод run() по таймеру

тоесть код может выглядеть примерно так:

```
class Test : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Test(QObject *parent = 0) : QObject(parent) {startTimer(0);}
signals:
    void exit();
public slots:
    void run() {emit exit();}
protected:
    void timerEvent(QTimerEvent *tev) {run();}
};
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    Test t;
    QObject::connect(&t, SIGNAL(exit()), &a, SLOT(quit()));
    return a.exec();
}
```

Вообще экземпляр QCoreApplication создается в том случае когда Вашей консольной программе нужна обработка каких либо событий. Если же этого не нужно то функцию main вполне можно писать в традиционном стиле:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    someFunction();
    ...
    moreFunction();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Первое предположение - t.run вызван раньше a.exec, сигнал-то он послал, а вот механизм обработки скорее всего еще не запустился (он стартует с a.exec). Кстати, а зачем `public slots: run`? Он же не используется в механизме сигналов-слотов.

Comment: да run() не обязана быть слотом, но цикл обработки на самом деле ловит сигналы из t.run(), если повесить их не на a.quit(), а на любой другой слот. поэтому я и задал вопрос